# Array multidimensional a partir de consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Boa tarde,

Tenho um sistema, com as seguintes tabelas :

```
pagina: id,nome ,icone, idGrupo.
paginaGrupo: id,nome,icone, idGrupoUser.
```

Estou montando um menu dinâmico em cima dessas tabelas. Pego os id dos grupos que o usuário faz parte, e jogo na query para pegar os Grupos de paginas e as paginas que ele terá acesso.

A query esta da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT gp.id as idG,gp.nome grupo,gp.uri uriG,gp.ordemMenu,gp.icone as iconeG,'
. 'p.id,p.name as pagina,p.uri uriP ,p.icon as iconeP from tblPaginas as p '
. 'inner join tblGrupoPaginas as gp '
. 'on (p.idGrupo = gp.id) '
. 'where gp.idGrupoAcesso IN('.implode(",",$this->getUserGrupoId() ).') '
. 'order by gp.ordemMenu ASC
```

Assim , obtenho esse retorno:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [idG] => 1 
        [grupo] => Monitoria de vendas
        [uriG] => monitoria-de-vendas 
        [ordemMenu] => 1 
        [iconeG] =>  
        [id] => 14 
        [pagina] => agenda 
        [uriP] => agenda 
        [iconeP] =>
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [idG] => 1 
        [grupo] => Monitoria de vendas 
        [uriG] => monitoria-de-vendas 
        [ordemMenu] => 1 
        [iconeG] =>  
        [id] => 15 
        [pagina] => paginas 
        [uriP] => paginas 
        [iconeP] =>  
    )
    [....]  
    [45] => Array ( 
        [idG] => 7 
        [grupo] => Ferramentas 
        [uriG] => ferramentas 
        [ordemMenu] => 8 
        [iconeG] =>  
        [id] => 10 
        [pagina] => equipamentos 
        [uriP] => equipamentos 
        [iconeP] =>  
    )
```

No array , tem o campo 'idG' ( id do grupo ).  Gostaria que o retorno fosse de um array multidimensional em cima do valor do campo 'idG'.

Se não tiver jeito de retornar pela query , como poderia fazer para criar esse array pelo PHP ?

Desde já , grato.

Comment: Acho que isso responde a sua dúvida: [php array group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group)

Comment: você usa `PDO` ou `Mysqli`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic , desculpe a demora, eu utilizo PDO.

Comment: @JoãoPinho, cara,  deu certo pelo link que você mandou.  Edito minha pergunta e coloco a resposta ou você responde aqui  ?

Comment: @HenriqueFelix tem uma forma com PDO é ao meu ver a correta!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic , opa como seria ? Atualmente faço dessa forma: public function getMenuPaginas(){
        
        try{
            
            $sql = 'cod sql';
            $stmt = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1){
                $linha = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $result = array();
                foreach ($linha as $data) {...} 
                return $result;
            }else { ... }
            
        } catch (Exception $ex) { ... }
        
    }// END FUNCTION

Comment: Olha eu refleti a minha resposta em um exemplo bem básico acredito que vai entender! @HenriqueFelix, se não pergunte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em comentários, é feito em [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php), nele mesmo tem um forma de agrupar por um determinado campo, onde ele deve ser o primeiro item da SQL, sendo esse campo a ***chave do array***:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero agrupar por `grupoid`, então, utilize `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`|`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` dentro do `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`:

```
<?php

   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbase','root','senha');
   $query = $pdo->query('SELECT grupoid, id, descricao FROM item ORDER BY grupoid');
   $query->execute();
   $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   var_dump($result);
```

Saida:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["descricao"]=>
      string(7) "Grupo 1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["descricao"]=>
      string(7) "Grupo 1"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["descricao"]=>
      string(7) "Grupo 2"
    }
  }
}
```

sendo que a chave é o `grupoid`.

***Link:***

- [Using PDO::fetchAll – Examples with codes and output results](http://blog.encodez.com/blog/using-pdofetchall-examples-with-codes-and-output-results)
- [PDOStatement::fetch](http://PDOStatement::fetch)

Comment: Deu certo , com o foreach rodou bem também , mas essa solução direto no   cod do PDO foi/vai ser uma mão na roda. Obrigado !

Comment: @HenriqueFelix, tudo (quase tudo) que é feito direto e a programação lhe dá utilize, o código é bom, mas, seria redundante se já existe algo melhor. Vlw...